# Generating Gaussian Distributed Random Numbers in C - how would one keep the values between 0 and 1

Tags: c, random, gaussian

I've been working on a function to generate gaussian distributed random randoms between zero and 1. [This website](http://www.taygeta.com/random/gaussian.html) here was a great help as I basically copied the algorithm for Polar Form to get an understanding of the procedure, but I am having trouble keeping the value between 0 and 1, including 0 but excluding 1. I believe the mathematical notation for this is [0, 1) if I'm correct. Any insight you could provide would be great. On Unix, this compiles with; gcc *fileName*.c -lm

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    float x, w;
    for (i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
        do {
            x = 2.0 * ( (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX ) - 1.0;
            w = x * x;
        }while (w >= 1.0);

        w = (float)sqrt( (-2.0 * log( w )) / w );
        printf("%f\n", x*w);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A gaussian distribution covers all real numbers. Why do you need to keep the values between 0 and 1?

Comment: To put it another way -- if the values are guaranteed to fall between 0 and 1, then they do not have a Gaussian distribution. They have some other distribution.

Comment: A 'genetic inheritance in plants' simulation I've been working on.

Comment: @SteveJessop could it be normalized distribution I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the questioner is asking for something like a *truncated gaussian distribution*.  You can sample such a distribution simply by generating samples from a Gaussian distribution with mean 0.5 and suitable variance, and discarding any samples that lie outside of [0,1].

However, you might also be interested in:

- [A logitnormal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logitnormal)
- [A uniform sum distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin-Hall_distribution)
- [A raised-cosine distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised_cosine_distribution)