# Normalized Random Number Distrubution Between 0 and 1 [0, 1) in C

Tags: c, random, normalization, normal-distribution

I'm having trouble keeping randomly generated values that are normally distributed between 0 and 1 (including 0, excluding 1). I believe the algorithm is basically correct, I am just stumped here. Any insight would be great.

These are the needed include files:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
```

The normally distributed random number generator function:

```
float rand_normal(float mean, float stddev) 
{
    static float n2 = 0.0;
    float x, y, r;
    static int n2_cached = 0;
    if (!n2_cached) 
    {
        do
        {
            x = 2.0*rand()/RAND_MAX - 1;
            y = 2.0*rand()/RAND_MAX - 1;
            r = x*x + y*y;
        } while (r==0.0 || r>1.0);
        float d = sqrt(-2.0*log(r)/r);
        float n1 = x*d;
        float result = n1*stddev + mean;
        n2 = y*d;
        n2_cached = 1;
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        n2_cached = 0;
        return n2*stddev + mean;
    }
}
```

main function used only for testing purposes.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    float min = 0.5, max = 0.5, r, avg = 0;
    float x, w;
    int n = 10000000;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        r = rand_normal(0.5, 0.09);
        if (r < min)
            min = r;
        else if ( r>max)
            max = r;
        avg += r;
    }
    avg /= (float)n;
    printf("min = %f\nmax = %f\navg = %f\n", min, max, avg);
    return 0;
}
```

In case anyone was wondering, this function is needed for a "genetic inheritance in plants" simulation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating Gaussian Distributed Random Numbers in C - how would one keep the values between 0 and 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930500/generating-gaussian-distributed-random-numbers-in-c-how-would-one-keep-the-val)

Comment: Yes, I did just post the question.  I was told that Gaussian Distribution was not what I was looking for and was referred to normal distribution instead, so this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: A normal distribution **is** a gaussian distribution.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution .  In particular, note that a Normal distribution has support on the entire real line, not only in the interval [0,1] (or any other interval, for that matter.)  Instead of trying to guess the name of the distribution you want and opening a duplicate question for each guess, please describe the *properties* that you want it to have -- we can help you identify the distribution that you're actually interested in.

Comment: Alternatively, you may be interested in Wikipedia's list of distributions supported on a bounded interval: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_a_bounded_interval

Comment: I'm looking for a function that will distribute values from 0 to 1, excluding 1, in a ['bell-curve'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) fashion.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you expect the result to stay between 0 and 1? The Gaussian distribution has full support, so whatever interval you are looking at and whatever the mean and variance you choose, there will always be a (possibility very small) non-zero probability of falling outside of that interval. If you really want to restrict yourself to [0,1] for some reason, then you can simply call rand_normal until you fall into that interval.

Note also that while Box-Müller (the algorithm you are using) is easy to implement, this is one of the worst and most costly ways of generating a Gaussian random variable. The best and fastest algorithm I know is the "Ziggurat" method, an implementation of which can be found at

http://www.seehuhn.de/pages/ziggurat

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely create a function to convert "rand()" to a normalized floating point value.  For example:

```
double
nrand ()
{
  return rand()/(RAND_MAX - 1);
}
```

Also, here are a few links that might help:

- http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx
- http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/normal/normal.html

Comment: This has equal probability over the entire range, not the bell curve that John is after.

Comment: @unwind - No, no, no!  "rand_normal()" is intended to produce the "bell curve".  The problem is that "2.0*rand()/RAND_MAX - 1" isn't producing normalized random numbers (random numbers between 0..1, excluding 1).  I suggested moving "2.0*rand()/RAND_MAX - 1" *OUT* of "rand_normal()".  I also suggested the two links might have some good tips, if my example wasn't enough.

Comment: @John - please consider wrapping "rand()" in a function to return a value between 0.0 and <1.0, please look at the links cited, and please post back how things go.  The whole problem might be as simple as missing a pair of parenthesis: perhaps "2.0*rand()/(RAND_MAX - 1)" instead of "2.0*rand()/RAND_MAX - 1".

Comment: The results were more accurate when I included a wrapper function for rand(), but values are still falling out of the 0-1 range (only slightly, though).

Comment: @John - how about "while ( (x = rand()/(RAND_MAX - 1)) >= 1.0); return x;"?

Comment: If you want doubles in the range [0, 1), you should `return rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0)`.  (Of course, the 1.0 can be replaced by some other positive number, the smallest `x` such that RAND_MAX/(RAND_MAX + x)` evaluates to `< 1` being optimal in some sense.)

Comment: The `x` above must be a `double` so that the division is performed in floating-point mode.